# In Ruby/Rails, how to get current value of column of queried model in a different model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am querying a model within a method in a different model's class. How can I refer to the queried model in some sort of "Rails Way" preferably? Please see the code to understand:

```
ModelA.where("id = ?", self.model_a_id).first.update_column(:attrbute_a, ???.attribute_a + self.attribute_b )
```

The "???" denotes how to refer to attribute a from Model A. I am using self to refer to Model B, the class I am currently inside of.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
model = ModelA.find(model_a_id)
model.update_column(:attribute_a, model.attribute_a + attribute_b)
```

BTW, why don't you use associations?